# Tips for simplifying

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on my homework for Uni. I'm stuck on some problems. I'm not looking for a solution, just some hints on how to do it.

1. $ \frac{3R^2-6Rv}{2v-R} \Leftrightarrow -3R$
2. I think here I'm also missing the same idea as in the problem above:
   $\frac{R}{v}-\frac{2t}{R} = \frac{R}{v+3t} \Leftrightarrow R =\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}v^2+2vt}$

Also: Sorry for my bad latex, I'm still learning. Any tips, advice or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: In your number 1 you have no equation at all in the left side...It also would be better if you ask (only( one of two questions in each thread, and not 7 (!)

Comment: I never said they were all equations. It's just a term I need to simplify. 1->7 is supposed to show the steps I did to attempt to solve the equation stated in 3 where I gave the equation and the solution. Again, sry for the bad markup. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: To simplify a fraction, you've got to factorize and cancel terms. To simplify a sum of fractions, first simplify the individual fractions as far as possible; then put everything over a common denominator; then try to simplify the result.

Comment: The symbol $\Leftrightarrow$ should only be used for equivalence of *statements*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{3R^2-6Rv}{2v-R}=3R\frac{R-2v}{2v-R}=-3R$$

or

$$\frac Rv-\frac{2t}R=\frac R{v+3t}\stackrel{\text{Mult. through by}\;R\cdot v\cdot(v+3t)}\implies R^2(v+3t)-2vt(v+3t)=R^2v\implies$$

$$\left(3t\right)R^2=2vt(v+3t)\implies R=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2v(v+3t)}{3}}\;\;,\;\;t\neq 0$$